# How to avoid code duplication in this example?

Tags: c++

I have two classes, `Base` and `Derived`. I provide a function that applies a function to all elements of `Base`, and another function to apply a function to all elements of `Derived`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Base {
  typedef std::vector<int> Vec;
  typedef Vec::const_iterator CIter;
  CIter begin() const;
  CIter end() const;
};

class Derived : public Base {
  void add(int);
};


template<class F>
void processBase(const Base& b, F& f) {
  for (Base::CIter it = b.begin(); it != b.end(); ++it) {
    f(b, *it);
  }
}

template<class F>
void processDerived(Derived* d, F& f) {
  for (Base::CIter it = d->begin(); it != d->end(); ++it) {
    f(d, *it);
  }
}
```

How can I make the one function call the other, so that I don't have code duplication? (I gave only a minimal example; in my real code the `for` loops are kind of complicated, and that code is exactly repeated in the two functions.)

Do I have to template the `processBase` function? Or is there a way to use casting?

Comment: Does `processBase(*d, f);` called from within processDerived() fail?

Comment: @MattPhillips `processBase(const Base&, F&)` and `processDerived(Derived*, F&)` aren't equivalent, they call the functor differentely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the `const Base&` vs. `Derived*` difference is an error, yes, you need a function template to call the functor with the correct argument type:

```
template <typename Collection, typename F>
void processCollection (Collection& col, F& f) {
    for (typename Collection::CIter i=col.begin(); i!=col.end(); ++i) {
        f (col, *i);
    }
}
```

`processCollection` works on `const` or non-`const`, `Base` or `Derived` objects.